# How to acces u-boot via ethernet?

Tags: serial-port, ethernet, u-boot

I have demoboard and it has an u-boot. In u-boot, I want to send command through ethernet rather than serial port(Like bootm 0x20000000 0x70000000). Actually, I want to use ethernet rather than serial port. Is this possible? If so, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide much more details such as what board you're using and if you're using mainline U-Boot or some vendor tree.  But the general answer is that yes, you can.  See http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.NetConsole;h=af7fc6043a3f3f02497f7527342b18551402be9d;hb=HEAD for more details on how to use netconsole.

Comment: I have p4080DS demo board. I am using u-boot which vendor provide not custom one.

Comment: If the file doc/README.NetConsole exists in the tree the vendor provided, it should be something you can enable and use.  P4080DS support also exists in mainline today.

Comment: After I set environment for target and typed "run nc" I got the following error.; "error inserting stdout variable errno=22".

Comment: Did you rebuild it with netconsole support?  22 is EINVAL.